# Function call with additional sub functions

Tags: javascript

I'm asking myself if it's possible to call a function in js, while having additional subfunction inside it

```
fn(s);

fn.subfn(s);
```

for example to make utils like this

```
var s = "123";
string(s) // true
string.blank(s) // false
```

I think it's possible like this:

```
function string(s) {
  if(s) return typeof(s) === "string";
  return {
    blank: function(s) {
      return s.trim().length === 0;
    }
  }
}
```

but every time i call string(s) i'm redefining blank fn, with possible poor performances and poor code, or i'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are just objects, so yes, you can just add properties to them:

```
function string(s) {
  return typeof(s) === "string";
}

string.blank = function(s) {
    return s.trim().length === 0;
}
```

This would allow you to make the calls

```
string(s);
string.blank(s);
```

just as shown in your example.

---

**Comments to your code:**

The function you defined *returns* an object when you call `string`, so you would require to call the function as

```
string().blank(s);
```

which would be different form the example you showed at the beginning.

Comment: mmh, i don't feel good having to call string() fn every time i need to check if it's blank

Comment: Yes, that's why you should do it as shown in my answer ;) Maybe I wasn't clear: The code *you* have would require to call make such a call.

Comment: @FelixKling The "example usage" is confusing user509375 because they thought it was part of your code and not how you are saying the original code would be employed. This is how I would answer the question though so +1

Comment: @PaulS.: There is line separating the two parts :-/ I will make it clearer though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
function string(s) {
  if(s) return typeof(s) === "string";
}

string.blank = function(s) {
  return s.trim().length === 0;
}
```

You might run into issues using "string" for the name of your function, though, because it may clash with the existing String object.

Comment: This way, `string.blank` is _undefined_, and I don't think _OP_ wanted to use `new`

Comment: very true. I'll remove the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Thing() class and instantiate "thing" objects to prevent redefining functions. (Thing() instead of string() to prevent any sort of collision.)

```
function Thing(s) {
    return {
        isString: function() {
            return typeof(s) === "string";
        },
        isBlank: function() {
            return s.trim().length === 0;
        }  
    };
}

var t = new Thing("123");
t.isString() // true
t.isBlank() // false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKrsa/

Comment: Why not save yourself a step and start with `var t = ObjLiteral`?